# DB2 Character Datatype and JPA Not Working

Tags: jpa, types, db2, character

I am working with DB2 Universal database having lots of tables with columns of datatype CHARACTER. Length of these columns is variable (greater than 1 e.g. 18). As i execute a Native query using JPA it selects only first character of the column. Seems CHARACTER datatype is mapped to Java Character.

How can i get full contents in DB column. I can not change the database bening on Vendor side. Please note i need to do it both ways, i.e. :

- Using JPQL ( is attribute columnDefinition can work in this case)
- Using native DB query (no pojo is used in this case and i have no control over datatypes)

i am using Hibernate implementation of JPA provided by spring.

Answer (score 1):

If these columns are actually common in your database, you can customize a dialect used by Hibernate. See comments to [HHH-2304](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2304).

Comment: i am using org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect provided by Spring. This does not contains registerXXX method. What class i actually need to extend.

Comment: Ok, the Databaseplatform property of jpaVendorAdapter is set as: <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" /> so i will be extending DBDialect. Let me try it.

Comment: It works fine. Is it possible to assign Varchar type to all columns having lenght > 1. If i specify a specific lenght, columns with exact lenght are mapped to varchar but other are not.

Comment: @Anyz: No, currently it's not possible. That's the reason why this problem can't be easily fixed in Hibernate code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cast the column to `VARCHAR` to produce padded String results from `createNativeQuery`:

```
select VARCHAR(char_col) from schema.tablename where id=:id
```